# How to change icon for a specific Content Type

Tags: document-library, content-type, file-icons

I have a collection of pdf documents that are considered Knowledge documents as they reside in a Knowledge Base and are curated.  They are in a Document Library and have a specific content type... Knowledge Document.

How does one go about changing the icon that represents a specific Content Type in a list, library, and Search Result?

Thanks!